# How to insert a new entry in Microsoft word Numbered list at number 1 and update the existing numbered list

Tags: microsoft-word

Hello I am using MS office 2013,

I have a numbered list as so ,

```
    1.Entry One
      1.1 someheading 1
         some text...
      1.2 someheading 1
         some text

    2.Entry Two
      2.1 someheading 2
          some text...  
      2.2 someheading 2
          some text 

and so on..
```

Now I want to enter a new entry to this list , but I want it to be at begining (i.e. number one) instead of being at the last,like so

```
    1.New entry
      1.1 someheading
         some text...
      1.2 someheading 
         some text

    2.Entry One
      2.1 someheading 1
          some text...  
      2.2 someheading 1
          some text 

    3.Entry Two
      3.1 someheading 2
          some text...  
      3.2 someheading 2
          some text
```

Is there a way to this ?

Comment: What happens when you try? Do you get an error?

Comment: how do I try , I want to use the MS numbering list and not add the numbers manually

Comment: Insert a new list item. Right click and select restart numbering.